# kerasのpythonでstackoverflowエラー

Tags: python, python3, numpy, keras, pillow

### 経緯

以下のプログラムを実行すると、stackoverflowエラーが出てしまいます。
どのようにすればいいのかがわからないのでわかる方、ご伝授お願いします。

### ソースコード

main.py

```py
# パッケージのインポート
import os

from keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Dense, Dropout
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm

import load_data


train_paths = []
for root, dirs, files in tqdm(os.walk("./font")):
    train_paths += list(map(lambda n:root+"/"+n,files))

val_count = int(len(train_paths) * 0.2)

train_gen = load_data.Generator(
                             train_paths[val_count:],
                             batch_size=64)
val_gen = load_data.Generator(
                             train_paths[:val_count],
                             batch_size=64)

# モデルの作成
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(32**2,)))  # 入力層
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='sigmoid'))  # 隠れ層
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))  # ドロップアウト
model.add(Dense(94, activation='softmax'))  # 出力層
# コンパイル
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=SGD(lr=0.1), metrics=['acc'])
# 学習
history = model.fit_generator(
           train_gen,
           steps_per_epoch=train_gen.num_batches_per_epoch,
           validation_data=val_gen,
           validation_steps=val_gen.num_batches_per_epoch,
           epochs=100,
           shuffle=True)
model.save("model.h5")
# model = load_model("model.h5")

# グラフの表示
plt.plot(history.history['acc'], label='acc')
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'], label='val_acc')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

load_data.py

```py
import numpy as np
import importlib
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
from keras.utils import Sequence


class Generator(Sequence):
    """Custom generator"""

    def __init__(self, data_paths, batch_size=1, width=32, height=32, font_size=32, num_of_class=94):
        """construction

        :param data_paths: List of image file
        :param batch_size: Batch size
        :param width: Image width
        :param height: Image height
        :param num_of_class: Num of classes
        """

        self.data_paths = data_paths
        self.length = len(data_paths) * 94 * int(180/5)
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.font_size = font_size
        self.num_of_class = num_of_class
        self.data_pos = [0, 0, 0]
        self.font_data = ImageFont.truetype(self.data_paths[self.data_pos[0]], self.font_size)
        self.num_batches_per_epoch = int((self.length - 1) / batch_size) + 1

    def _load_data(self):
        text = chr(self.data_pos[2] + 33)
        font_path = self.data_paths[self.data_pos[0]]
        font_color = "white"
        rot = self.data_pos[1]*5

        # get fontsize

        tmp = Image.new('RGBA', (1, 1), (0, 0, 0, 0))  # dummy for get text_size

        tmp_d = ImageDraw.Draw(tmp)
        text_size = tmp_d.textsize(text, self.font_data)
        i = self.font_size
        while text_size[0] > self.font_size - 5 or text_size[1] > self.font_size - 5:
            i -= 1
            font_data = ImageFont.truetype(font_path, i)
            text_size = tmp_d.textsize(text, font_data)
        # draw text

        img = Image.new('RGBA', [self.font_size] * 2, (0, 0, 0, 0))  # background: transparent

        img_d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
        img_d.text((0, 0), text, fill=font_color, font=self.font_data)
        img = img.rotate(rot)

        self.data_pos[2] += 1
        if self.data_pos[2] > 93:
            self.data_pos[1] += 1
            self.data_pos[2] = 0
            if self.data_pos[1] > 180/5:
                importlib.reload(np)
                importlib.reload(Image)
                importlib.reload(ImageDraw)
                importlib.reload(ImageFont)
                importlib.reload(importlib)
                self.data_pos[0] += 1
                self.font_data = ImageFont.truetype(self.data_paths[self.data_pos[0]], self.font_size)
                self.data_pos[1] = 0

        img = np.array(img)
        img = 0.299 * img[:, :, 2] + 0.587 * img[:, :, 1] + 0.114 * img[:, :, 0]
        return img, self.data_pos[2]

    def __getitem__(self, idx) -> np.array:
        """Get batch data

        :param idx: Index of batch

        :return imgs: numpy array of images
        :return labels: numpy array of label
        """

        start_pos = self.batch_size * idx
        end_pos = start_pos + self.batch_size
        if end_pos > self.length:
            end_pos = self.length
        imgs = np.empty((end_pos-start_pos+1, self.height, self.width), dtype=np.float32)
        labels = np.zeros((end_pos-start_pos+1, self.num_of_class), dtype=np.int16)

        for i in range(self.batch_size):
            img, label = self._load_data()
            imgs[i, :] = img
            labels[i][label] = 1
        np.save("test.npy", labels)
        # データセットの画像の前処理
        imgs = imgs.reshape((imgs.shape[0], imgs.shape[1] ** 2))

        return imgs, labels

    def __len__(self):
        """Batch length"""

        return self.num_batches_per_epoch

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        """Task when end of epoch"""
        pass
```

よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: 通知されたエラーメッセージの全部を質問に追記するか、それを基に他の人が検証出来る程度に問題個所を特定するかプログラムを削っていって、テスト用のデータも提示してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。フォントが肥大すぎてtry exceptで挟まなくてはエラーが起きてしまっていました。ご迷惑おかけしました。